# How to check whether some product belongs to some category

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I try to make web application with the help of laravel. In my application I have products and categories. One product can has many categories and one category can has many products. You can see this relations on the next picture:

[image]

On frontend I have following:
[image]

As you can see this is select with multiple. I need to show in this select all categories and categories for particular product must be selected (attribute 'selected').

Maybe somebody knows which query I need to write for Eloquent ORM? I would like to have on my view result collection that has all categories and some field for each category, where will information whether this product to this category or not.

Here are my models

Product

```
 public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category',
        'category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

And Category

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product',
        'category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

UPDATE:
I need following data structure. Or something like this
[image]

In this array (collection maybe) I would like to see all categories and the field that will say me is this product on this category or not.

Comment: You can get the categories assigned to a product using `$product->categories`.

Comment: It's look like simple. I will try.

Comment: It's does not work. This code returns me empty collection. But I definetly know that there is two categories for this product

    $product = Product::with('photo')->where('id', $id)->get()->first();
         if($request->isMethod('get')){
         $categories = Category::all();
         dd($product->categories);
        // ...

Comment: Can you post the select's view code?